# Infopath Form buttons is not responding SP2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath, infopath2010

i created an InfoPath form with some views and rules and published it to SharePoint 2013
...it works OK .. but suddenly after some seconds it stop responding to any action from my buttons and the title of the site turned to the link otherwise the site name
.. the form is a web service form

any help ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you answer my question ? Do you have any validation which firesparticularly in the one view field ?

Is this behavior occur when you change the view and after entering all the data submitting the form ?

If yes, then check that the validation for the previous view is disabled for the particualr field.

Otherwise you will not be able to submit the form

Please correct me if i misunderstood your question